# Magento2: Mailchimp Error: Script error for: campaigncatcher

Tags: magento-2.1, mailchimp

My Magento version is 2.1.4 and Mailchimp version is 1.0.25.
The issue is, when I enable Mailchimp extension, the checkout page is not working properly. We are using Mageplaza's Onestepcheckout extension for checkout. On disabling Mailchimp, everything works fine.
Firebug shows following error on checkout page:

```
Error: Script error for: campaigncatcher
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
```

Can someone tell me what could be the issue here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also, when creating store at backend, showing following error in firebug: >>>>>>>>
Error: Script error for: monkeyapikey
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
>>>>>>>>

Comment: run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` should resolve your issue.

Comment: @AmanAlam Thanks for quick response. But upgrade command is already executed so many times, that didn't fix issue. :(

Comment: Have you check `campaigncatcher` is exist in module please check ones

Comment: you should get this file `vendor/namespace/module/web/js/` folder

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Aman for the clue.

I've fixed the issue by executing upgrade command first and then deploying content.

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable 
php bin/magento setup:upgrade 
php setup:static-content:deploy (Deploy for each language of the store separately) 
php bin/magento maintenance:disable 
php -f bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope this helps someone. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks. Totally forgot to flush. lol